# Can I declare a function named CURSES in C?

Tags: c, linux

On the Linux platform, I get compile errors for using a function named `CURSES`.  If I change the name to something else such as "my_curses" there are no more errors.
I understand there is a `curses.h` but I'm not aware of any functions named `CURSES`.  Is there a function that already exists called `CURSES` in the standard or built in libraries?

**PROTOTYPE:**
`void CURSES(int x)`

**ERROR:**
"error: syntax error before numeric constant"

Then in the function declaration I get a bunch of similar errors along with a bunch of errors with "conflicting types".

Comment: There possibly is a preprocessor-definition for `CURSES`. Could you please give your `#include`s?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you calling it `curses` or `CURSES`? You might be in conflict with a macro name.

Comment: Have you tried using the function? The compiler can tell you if it exists or not.

Comment: Best way to check for an existing preprocessor macro would be to `#define CURSES(x) ((x)+42)`. that would give a 'redefinition' error. Or `#ifdef CURSES #error CURSES!@#$#@ #endif` BTW: is it so hard to give your function a different name?

Comment: the function is called CURSES.

Comment: @SS. I edited your question to consistently use the name `CURSES`. It is important that questions are clear and unambiguous.

Comment: I would recommending posting a minimal, complete example of a source file that causes you to get this error, including any `#include` declarations at the top. If I just compile a simple test program that only includes `stdio.h`, for example, I do not get this error.

Comment: wildplasser:  Its not the fact that I needed to get it to compile without errors it was me trying to understand why this was happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CURSES is probably a define. So your options are:

- #undef CURSES --- that's not a good option unless you exactly know WHERE and by WHO this define is used.
- call your function Curses, or cURSES or simply curses.
- change name to your function.

Edit: A simple grep on my includes told me that both curses.h and ncurses.h have this line

```
#define CURSES 1
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for chiming in.  I really appreciate it.  So it turns out one of my other .h files that I included actually calls out curses.h   I tried "curses" instead of "CURSES" and no more issues so it must have been the #define CURSES 1 in curses.h causing this issue.

Comment: @SS. You can use `gcc -H` (plus any other compiler options you need) to see the list of headers that are included by your program.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: Can I declare a function named curses in C?

A: Sure.  "curses()" and "CURSES()" are both legal names.

> Q: ERROR: "error: syntax error before numeric constant"

It would be helpful if you pasted the code immediately before, after and including the error line.  It's probably something simple.  Maybe you just forgot the ";" after the prototype?

EXAMPLE:

```
void CURSES(int x);
```

ALSO:

1) It's entirely possible there's a conflict with some other, *different* function or #define "CURSES".  Check your #include's (or cut/paste your #include's into your post).

2) "CURSES" is a legal function name ... but it's a poor choice.  I would only use capital letters for #define macro's (and not function names).

EXAMPLE:

```
#define MY_MACRO(x)

void my_function (int x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiler says this is not a function name, but a constant

Decision is using another name.

Answer (score -4):

You have a prototype declaration `void CURSES(int x)`. That is invalid, in C the prototype declaration should be: `void CURSES(int)`. Then your function implementation/declaration is something like:

```
void CURSES(int x) {
    printf("Curses! Got: %d\n", x);
}
```

Comment: No, declaration can be performed the both ways.

Comment: Nonsense!  "void some_function (int my_integer);" is a perfectly legimate prototype.  "void some_function (int);" without the argument name is a maintenance nightmare.  I would *ALWAYS* include the argument name!